# short text categorization with spelling correction

Tags: reference-request, machine-learning, natural-language-processing, classification

I am building a classifier for short texts in a chat system. My features are words and pairs of words.

Naturally, the sentences contain spelling mistakes. If a particular wrong spelling of a certain word hasn't appeared in the training corpus, the classifier has no chance to identify it.

I consider taking an existing spelling corrector, and integrate it with my current classifier, but I am not sure how to do it.

Do you know of a paper that integrates an automatic spelling correction tool with a short text classifier?

Answer (score 1):

Could you not just pre-process the text? Simply pass over the corpus and correct errors via edit-distance or lookup tables. Once this has finished you can then run the classifier.

It you *really* want to incorporate the correction into your model, it would seem that you can re-define edit distance to compute the log-probability of some misspelled word matching another for some mismatch probability $\theta \sim \text{Beta}(\alpha, \beta)$.

The resulting probabilities can then be incorporated into the classifier directly, which would be parameterized by $\theta$. Depending on how complex your internal model is, you could find the ML or MAP estimate $\hat{\theta}$ by some EM algorithm, or if the model allows, analytically.

Comment: This is an obvious simplification, as the probability of substituting a letter may be different than inserting or leaving it out, but should still give a decent idea on how to incorporate it.

Comment: The problem with pre-processing is that, no speller is perfect. The chatters might use a word that the speller doesn't knowm, and the speller will mistakenly change it.